# Encounter of a error in c++ (code::blocks)

Tags: c++11, runtime-error, codeblocks

For a few days I have been encountering this problem.
The problem is that I am not able to use `cin.getline()` and `gets()` function.
The program compiles perfectly but during execution these statements doesn't work at all.
It seems that the program skips them.
What should I do? is there any alternative to these functions? The piece of code is similar to the sample given below.

```
while(I<10)
{ cout <<"Enter a string:";
cin.getline(str, 40);
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: Please share the relevant code so I can see if you're using the functions correctly.

Comment: Please, note that gets has been deprecated and now removed from the Standard http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets